# Pass scope to mixin

Tags: css, sass

I have the following mixin for common active / hover states of an element:

```
@mixin hover-states {
  &:hover, &:active, &:focus {
    @content;
  }
}
```

This works when I use it like this

```
.myClass {
  @include hover-states {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

However, when I want to use the parent ampersand notation, this doesn't work:

```
.myClass {
  .myParent & {
    @include hover-states {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

The desired behaviour is, **when the parent is hovered, the child element should change it's style.** But this code compiles to the following CSS:

```
.myParent .myClass:hover, .myParent .myClass:active, .myParent .myClass:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it should look like this

```
.myParent:hover .myClass, .myParent:active .myClass, .myParent:focus .myClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Is there any method (or notation?) to pass the desired scope to the mixin, so that the `&:hover` refers to the parent element and not to the child element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `selector-nest` function to get your desired result

```
.myParent {
  @include hover-states {
    @at-root #{selector-nest(&, '.myClass')} {
      color: green;
    }
  }
}
```

The compiled css looks like this

```
.myParent:hover .myClass, .myParent:active .myClass, .myParent:focus .myClass {
  color: green;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is, that I want to use the parent ampersand notation `.myClass { .myParent & { ... } }`. If you use normal nesting, you can completely remove the `selector-nest` and just do a `.myParent { @include hover-states { .myClass { color: green; } } }`